# How to provide my own ediff-make-wide-display-function for ediff

Tags: ediff, buffer-local, defvar

For Ediff's wide display feature I like to use my own `ediff-make-wide-display` function. Ediff has a variable for this: `ediff-make-wide-display-function`. However when I write:

```
(defun my-ediff-make-wide-display ()
   ...)

(setq ediff-make-wide-display-function #'my-ediff-make-wide-display)
```

my definition doesn't seem to get used when I toggle the display to wide view. I guess the reason is that `ediff-make-wide-display-function` is defined as a local variable (via `ediff-defvar-local`),  and my `setq` call sets the variable somewhere else...

So to which buffers is the definition local and how can I set it for all of these buffers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've diagnosed the issue correctly, and you can either:

1. Use `ediff-mode-hook` to set the buffer-local value.
2. Use `setq-default` to set the default value.

Offhand I think #2 seems like the best option.

Comment: Using `setq-default` works perfectly. Thanks. - Just out of curiosity, what would I need to use in `ediff-mode-hook`? `setq-local`?

Comment: You can do, but because this variable "Automatically becomes permanently buffer-local when set" you could also just use `setq`. (The "permanently" isn't important here, but means it also survives changes to the major mode.)

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.